# New Typescript 1.8.4 build error: " Build: Property 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'. "

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

I am New to typescript. In my Durandal application I migrated to VS-2012 to VS-2015 means typescript 0.9 to typescript 1.8.4. After migrated I got so many build errors. I resolved all those except one. I am getting below build error on types of Events.

**ERROR: " Build: Property 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' "**

And the code was exactly like this below:

```
var reader:any,
target:EventTarget;

reader= new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (imgsrc){
    var fileUrl = imgsrc.target.result;
}
```

"Imgsrc" is taking type event.

It's working fine with typescript 0.9 but with 1.8.4 it's throwing error as 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'. 
Can any one help on this to resolve.

**Note: "target:EventTarget" is getting from lib.d.ts**

Answer (score 76, accepted):

While **`any`** is a medicine *(almost for anything, but... where is the TypeScript benefit then)*... there is a similar issue reported and nice *(TypesScript-ish)* workaround suggested

#### [Request to change currentTarget in Event interface for lib.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/299#issuecomment-168538829)

let me cite:

> I ran into this TS2339: Property 'result' does not exist on type
>   'EventTarget' in JS FileReader onload, and another warning for
>   getSummary() on the event passed to FileReader's onerror.
>
> My work-around, to suppress the horrid red squiggily lines;-) is the
>   following:
>
> ```
> interface FileReaderEventTarget extends EventTarget {
>     result:string
> }
>
> interface FileReaderEvent extends Event {
>     target: FileReaderEventTarget;
>     getMessage():string;
> }
> ```
>
> Then in my app:
>
> ```
> reader.onload = function(fre:FileReaderEvent) {
>     var data = JSON.parse(fre.target.result);
>     ...
> }
> ```

And, until some change in lib.d.ts, we still do work with known interface

EDIT Dec 2019:

With this fix, you might be getting

> error TS2322: Type '(this: FileReader, e: FileReaderEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '(this: FileReader, ev: ProgressEvent) => any'.

If so, just replace

```
 interface FileReaderEvent extends Event {
```

with

```
 interface FileReaderEvent extends ProgressEvent {
```

Comment: Still unfixed as of late April 2018

Comment: Still unfixed as of early June 2018

Comment: Still unfixed as of late July 2018

Comment: Still unfixed as of late August 2018

Comment: Still unfixed. October 2018.

Comment: still unfixed. Nov 4,2018

Comment: Still unfixed as of Jan 2019

Comment: I needed to use `ArrayLike<number>` instead of `string` in the FileReaderEventTarget interface.

Comment: Still unfixed as of March 2019

Comment: Still unfixed as of May 2019

Comment: Still unfixed. July 2019

Comment: Still unfixed. Sept 2019

Comment: Still unfixed. Oct 2019

Comment: Still unfixed as of `Jan 2019`

Comment: Still not fixed as of `19 Nov 2019` :(

Comment: No need to create your own interface. You can use FileReader (which extends EventTarget) from lib.dom.ts to cast the event

Comment: Added a slight tweak that may be needed for some (just like for me)

Comment: Still unfixed as of Jan 2020

Comment: Still unfixed as of April 2020

Comment: Still unfixed as of May 2020

Comment: Still unfixed as of June 2020

Comment: Still unfixed as of July 2020

Comment: Still unfixed as of August 2020

Comment: Still unfixed as of Jan 2021

Comment: Still unfixed as of Sep 2021

Comment: Still unfixed as of Jan 2022

Comment: Still unfixed as of Mar 2023

Answer (score 87):

Instead of using `event.target.result`, you can just use `FileReader.result`.

For example,

```
const fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.onload = (event: Event) => {
   event.target.result; // This is invalid
   fileReader.result; // This is valid
};
```

Comment: can't parse as a json :(

Comment: @KimchiMan.. Great ... Can you explain how.?

Comment: If this error comes<br>
**Type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'** <br/>
> fileReader.result;+'';

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, clean and no hacks involved

Comment: Actually its `ProgressEvent<FileReader>` and not just `Event`...

Comment: And if you get this error - 'Type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string' ' you can simply typecast as provided here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54089823/13596406

Answer (score 37):

With my old type script the parameter "imgsrc" is having any type by default.

So, now I made it as (imgsrc:any). It's working fine.

```
var reader:any,
target:EventTarget;
reader= new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (imgsrc:any){
var fileUrl = imgsrc.target.result;
}
```

Answer (score 22):

The issue is with the typescript definitions. A simple cheat is:

```
let target: any = e.target; //<-- This (any) will tell compiler to shut up!
let content: string = target.result;
```

Answer (score 19):

Just let TypScript know what type you would expect it to be.

Here is the fix:

```
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (event){
    let fileUrl = (<FileReader>event.target).result;
}
```

You could also use `reader.result` instead in this case

Comment: This is the best solution

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is finding the simplest solution then
[this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/299#issuecomment-551202504) worked for me.

```
var reader:any,
target:EventTarget;
reader= new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (imgsrc){
//var fileUrl = imgsrc.target.result; //change to
var fileUrl = (imgsrc.target as FileReader).result; //cast to correct type
}
```

Answer (score 4):

After lib.dom.d.ts analyzation it is simple:

```
const fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.onload = (event: ProgressEvent<FileReader>) => {
   event.target.result; // This is valid
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Today this worked for me at TypeScript 2.1.1

```
interface EventTarget { result: any; }
```

Comment: Nice solution, however when I restarted the solution it gives many errors in the lib.d.ts. It collides with the real EventTarget interface.

Answer (score 2):

If this error comes
**Type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'**

> fileReader.result+' ';//valid 
>   fileReader.result; //invalid

Answer (score 2):

The above solutions didn't fit my similar issue with IndexedDB so I thought I'd share what did work in my scenario. By changing the `(event)` functions' arguments to `(event: any)` I was able to ignore the type errors.

Sample Code:

```
let request = window.indexedDB.open('userChannels', 3);

request.onerror = function(event: any ) {
    console.log('ERROR: Failed to create userChannels local DB' + event.target.errorCode)
  };

request.onsuccess = function(event: any) {
   let db = event.target.result;
   console.log('SUCCESS: Created userChannels local DB')
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in angular with a `FileReader`.

The solution is rather simple (Typescript has the necessary type). You have to use `ProgressEvent<FileReader>`. It can be found im `lib.dom.d.ts` in the typescript installation, so it should be globally availabe if you build with

```
lib: {
"dom"
}
```

in your `tsconfig.json`.

Here is the code where i had to use it:

```
function read(file: File) {
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onloadend = function (e: ProgressEvent<FileReader>) {
    const arr = (new Uint8Array(parseInt(e.target.result.toString(), 10))).subarray(0, 4);
    var header = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      header += arr[i].toString(16);
    }
    console.log(header);

    // Check the file signature against known types

  };
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
    this.localDbRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
      const db = event.target.result;
    };
```

do

```
   this.localDbRequest.onsuccess = function (event) {
     const db = this.result;
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

The *target* object can be accessed as below to prevent error until fix:

```
reader= new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (imgsrc){
    var fileUrl = imgsrc.target["result"];
}
```

Treating the target as a Javascript Object

Answer (score 0):

this is a break change of javascript/typescript.

what you will need to do is to just replace "event.target.result" by "this.result".

"this" here refers to the context of interface "MSBaseReader".

below are my implementation excerpt:

```
      let reader = new FileReader();
      let profile: TransProfile = new TransProfile();

      reader.onload = function(event){
        profile.avatar = new Uint8Array(this.result);
      }

      reader.onerror = function(event){
      }

      this.photoLib.getPhoto(item)
        .then(blob => reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob))
        .then(() => this.doUpload(profile));
```

"MSBaseReader" interface definition:

```
interface MSBaseReader {
    onabort: (this: MSBaseReader, ev: Event) => any;
    onerror: (this: MSBaseReader, ev: ErrorEvent) => any;
    onload: (this: MSBaseReader, ev: Event) => any;
    onloadend: (this: MSBaseReader, ev: ProgressEvent) => any;
    onloadstart: (this: MSBaseReader, ev: Event) => any;
    onprogress: (this: MSBaseReader, ev: ProgressEvent) => any;
    readonly readyState: number;
    readonly result: any;
    abort(): void;
    readonly DONE: number;
    readonly EMPTY: number;
    readonly LOADING: number;
    addEventListener<K extends keyof MSBaseReaderEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: MSBaseReader, ev: MSBaseReaderEventMap[K]) => any, useCapture?: boolean): void;
    addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, useCapture?: boolean): void;
}
```

"FileReader" interface definition

```
interface FileReader extends EventTarget, MSBaseReader {
    readonly error: DOMError;
    readAsArrayBuffer(blob: Blob): void;
    readAsBinaryString(blob: Blob): void;
    readAsDataURL(blob: Blob): void;
    readAsText(blob: Blob, encoding?: string): void;
    addEventListener<K extends keyof MSBaseReaderEventMap>(type: K, listener: (this: FileReader, ev: MSBaseReaderEventMap[K]) => any, useCapture?: boolean): void;
    addEventListener(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, useCapture?: boolean): void;
}
```

also note that, due to the context change of "this" within "onload()", your class-based definitions are not accessible within "reader.onload = function(event){..."; meaning you can not use "this.class-property" style to address your class properties.

you will have to define local variable. see the definition and usage of "profile" in above excerpt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
event.target["result"]
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.