# Angular not recognizing event result

Tags: angular, data-binding, event-handling

I am working on a group project. We are adding a picture upload feature to a component. I keep getting an error that there is no 'result', but there clearly is, and the code runs beautifully from the same branch on other machines.

switching branches, uninstall reinstall angular cli, exorcism

here's the ts code:

```
export class ProfilePictureComponent implements OnInit {
  url: string;
  onSelectFile(event) { // called each time file input changes
      if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url

        reader.onload = (event) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
          this.url = event.target.result as string;
        }
      }
  }
```

here's the template:

```
<div id="img-div" *ngIf="url; else nourl">
        <img [src]="url" height="200" width="200"> <br />
    </div>
    <div id="img-default">
            <ng-template #nourl>
                    <img src="./empty.jpg" height="200" width="200">
            </ng-template>
    </div>
    <input type='file' (change)="onSelectFile($event)">
```

for brevity am omitting root module and import/exports. these seem fine as the code runs as is on other machines.

```
ERROR in src/app/profile-picture/profile-picture.component.ts:17:35 - error TS2339: Property 'result' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

17           this.url = event.target.result as string;
```

I expect the code to compile fine.

Comment: Can you do a `console.log( event.target.result)`?

Comment: ````Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:4200/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.````

Comment: you could try and cast the `event.target` to `any` like `this.url = (event.target as any).result;` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35789498/new-typescript-1-8-4-build-error-build-property-result-does-not-exist-on-t

Comment: You sir, are a Golden God, I am live.

Answer (score 0):

The input change method holds the data in `event.target.value` attribute.
refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event