# how to get the value from a Promise resolve?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, async-await

I am trying to read user uploaded file and convert it into String. I have 2 functions to do this.

**handleFileInput**

```
handleFileInput(event){
  setTimeOut(async()=>{
   let abcd= await this.convertFileToString(this.file) //the file has been uloaded successFully at this point
   console.log(abcd) //this prints the enitre fn given in the resolve method
  },3000)
}
```

**convertFileToString**

```
convertFileToString(file){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      let fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsText(file);
      resolve(fileReader.onload = (event) =>{
        this.XMLAsString=fileReader.result as String 
      })
    })
}
```

When i print the value of `abcd` in the console i get this:

```
ƒ (event) {
                _this.XMLAsString = fileReader.result;
            }
```

I am fairly new to the concept of `async/await` and `Promises` and understand that promise is the only asynchronous thing i can await. I want the value of the uploaded file (converted to String) to be stored in variable `abcd`. how do i get the value? Or if i have to return a promise, then how do i access the value of file read as String and store in in `abcd`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `convertFileToString` looks a little wrong: you should be invoking `resolve()` in the `onload` handler, not the other way round:

```
convertFileToString(file){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      let fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsText(file);
      fileReader.onload = (event) => {
          resolve(event.target.result);
      }
    })
}
```

Comment: this gives the following error: ```Property 'result'
does not exist on type 'EventTarget'```

Comment: @SamarthSaxena look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35789498/new-typescript-1-8-4-build-error-build-property-result-does-not-exist-on-t

Comment: @Terry Your solution worked. Instead of writing ```resolve(event.target.result)``` I wrote this: ```this.XMLAsString=fileReader.result as String;      resolve(this.XMLAsString)```Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @SamarthSaxena Use `(event.target as FileReader).result` then. Or just use a closure: `resolve(fileReader.result)`

Comment: @SamarthSaxena Glad to help :)